# How can i show a confirm dialog when a user clicks a button in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a number of buttons in my react app and i want to display a confirmation when the user clicks on the button. If they select yes then the action on the button is performed else not . Issue is that i want different message to be displayed for each button , For example "are you sure you want to delete the user" , Are you sure you want to delete the server" etc
How can i do this in reactjs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `window.confirm()` function, it is available in react too and you can put it in the button handler

Comment: Is there an example

Comment: There are many on https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp and on other sites they are available for React too.